# How to tell the difference between elk and hunters using elk calls?

Tags: bow-hunting, elk

Sometimes when hunting elk, especially archery, you will hear elk calls and be unsure whether it is an elk or a human using an elk call.

How could one tell the difference?

Comment: Firmly attached antlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricks are,

- Humans carry both bugle (bull) and cow calls, while a bull elk won't make cow noises. So hearing a bugle and then a cow call from the same place is almost guaranteed to be a human.
- Humans can be over eager to respond and will bugle back very quickly while elk will take a while.
- Elk move around while humans will usually stay in the same spot as they are hoping the elk comes to them.
- Bull elk will vary their calls, but humans usually only carry one bugle call and that leads to it sounding pretty much the same.